# Prevent comment on a post ID that has not been retrived with xpath

Tags: php

Im currently working on a small commenting system, where you can comment on a specific book. The thing is that the books are retrieved from another server, with XPath.

So to view the comments, i can head over to `www.example.com/comment/view/12277`, and i will be able to read and make comments on that book (with id 12277).

But, if I head over to `www.example.com/comment/view/11111`, that has not been fetch with xpath, and is not a valid book ID. I will still be able to make comments on that ID.

I could make another XPath query, to validate the ID, but that would create unnecessary bandwidth load on server(s).

**How this currently flows** is that a list of available books are retrived from a model, and the model also acquire the book ID. Then the controller renders `www.example.com/books`.

So on `/books` i have a list

```
<a href="www.example.com/books/16760/">Book 1</a> 
<a href="www.example.com/books/20208/">Book 2</a>
and so on.
```

## My question:

Can I prevent users to head over to a ID, that doesent exist? Without making a (another) validation query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I prevent users to head over to a ID, that doesent exist? Without making a (another) validation query?

You can't.

Clients can send whatever request they like to the server.

That request can be "Add a comment for 9999999".

You can't stop that. Everything beyond the borders of your server is outside your control.

You can only receive the request and check that 9999999 exists.